# Generating increasing number

Tags: php, list, html-lists

I Have a ordered list and i want to generate a incemental number for the **data-slide-to** starting from 0

That is the php code
          get("display_indicators", 1)): ?>
           
            $item){
                    $activeclass = "";
                    if($key == 0){
                        $activeclass = "active";
                    }
                    ?>

id;?>" data-slide-to="" class="">

Comment: Please, correct your question, it's impossible to read it.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to contain a counter...

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>

<li data-target="#carousel<?php echo $module->id;?>" data-slide-to="<?php
echo $counter;
$counter++;
?>" class="<?php echo $activeclass; ?>"></li>
```

You could even use the following instead of echo-ing and incrementing on two lines...

```
echo $counter++;
```

This echoes the current count and increments afterwards, but some people prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it'll help you

```
<?php $uniqueNo=0; ?>    
<li data-target="#carousel<?php echo $module->id;?>" data-slide-to="
<?php echo $uniqueNo+=1; ?>" class="<?php echo $activeclass; ?>"></li>
```

Comment: I try this but in the first li appear this error     Notice: Undefined variable: uniqueNo in C:\wamp\www\joomla\2013\testspace\modules\mod_carousel\tmpl\default.php on line 29 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006339976{main}( )..\index.php:0 21.15659246624JSite->render( )..\index.php:58 
The second and third li are ok with id 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use an incremential counter

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>

<ul>
enter code here
<li data-target="#carousel<?php echo $module->id;?>" data-slide-to="<?=$counter++?>"
class="<?php echo $activeclass; ?>"></li>
```

this however could not be "unique" application wide